# How to show the header and adjacent cell values of two lowest values in a row in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make a comparative statement in excel 2013 of a rate inquiry for purchases.

The top row contains the name of the vendors, below each vendors name there are two columns, first showing quoted price and the next column showing brand offered.

At the end of the row I have three columns first showing lowest quoted price, next showing the name of he vendor offering that lowest price and next column showing the brand being offered by that vendor.

I have done this much by using MIN, INDEX MATCH AND OFFSET INDEX MATCH Function.

The problem is when two vendors offer the minimum price. I want the next two columns to show the name of the second vendor who offers the same minimum price and the brand it is offering. Please help me with this.

Comment: Could you include sample data with expected output?

Comment: So far I have created a sheet where two columns under the name of each Vendor, one shows his quote and the next shows the brand offered, then the next vendor and so on. At the end of the row I have put the formula Min(A4:N4).This gives me the minimum quote, in next cell I put the formula Index(A2:N2,MATCH(M4,A4:N4,0),this gives the name of the Vendor with minimum quote. In the next column I used the Offset function with the index function above modified to give the contents of the cell next to the one with minimum quote which gives the brand offered with minimum quote. So far it's ok, the prob

Comment: Sorry the comment got shortened. So far it's ok, the problem arises when there are two Vendors giving the same minimum quote. So far we have been doing the manual checking adding that vendor. This increases the time required and increases the chances of error. I want Excel to do it automatically. I am sure it can be done.  I will be grateful if you could help me do this. Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  You can start a Query from an Excel Table or Named Range.

Power Query has a "Group By" button which can calculated a Minumum value.  I would save this as the first Query, but not Load the results to a table.

Then I would start a second Query from the same source table, and use the Merge button to restrict it to Vendors with the same price as the Minimum value.  I would deliver that result to a new Excel Table.

In the future you can just refresh the 2nd Query to recalculate the result.